# Form closed event not triggered in parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I am having a bit of a head scratch moment at the moment.

I have 2 `Forms` one being a Parent form and other being the child form.

Inside the Parent form am trying to detect the `FormClosed` event which I have subscribed to a event inside the Parent form to handle some behaviour.

However the `FormClosed` event never gets subscribed or triggered when I close the child Form? I am not really sure what am doing wrong? I have even tried `FormClosing` and nothing gets triggered?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var frm2 = new Form2())
        {
            frm2.ShowDialog();
            frm2.FormClosed += Frm2OnFormClosed;
        }
    }

    private void Frm2OnFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Implement further behaviour handling.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShowDialog() will block execution of code in the calling method until the new form is closed. So you are opening and closing frm2 before you've ever even assigned the EventHandler. Switch your two lines around like so and you should be good to go:

```
frm2.FormClosed += Frm2OnFormClosed;
frm2.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Bravo!! that makes absolute sense. Thank you :) That solved my issue.